# Numerical solution of driven infinite well with Floquet matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, optical-lattices

I am trying to understand and replicate figure 3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.09042).

The idea is that we have our box with a periodic drive
$$H(t) = \frac{p^2}{2m}-F_0x\cos(\omega t)$$
The author states

> In order to calculate the truncated time-evolution matrix $U(T, 0)$ one takes each of the unperturbed box eigenstates as initial condition, $ψ_n(x, 0) = ϕ_n(x)$, and computes the states $ψ_n(x, T )$ resulting after one period, collecting these state vectors as columns of the monodromy matrix

I am having difficulty figuring this out.  I know the unperturbed energies and wavefunctions $|\psi(0)\rangle$.  I also know that $|\psi(t)\rangle = U(t,0)|\psi(0)\rangle$
with ($\hbar=1$)

$$U(t,0)=\exp\left[-i\int_0^tH \ dt\right]$$
This is where I am unsure of how to numerically calculate.   Usually, I would do just $\psi(t)=\psi(0)\exp[-iE_n t]$, but because of the periodicity, we actually are able to expand
$$U(t,0)=\sum_n |n\rangle\langle n| \exp[-i\epsilon_n T]$$
In quasi-energies, which I want to solve for, so I am not sure of the time dependance of H to integrate to solve for $|\psi(x,t)\rangle$.  Any suggestions on how to approach this are appreciated.

Comment: Note that your first expression for $U(t,0)$ is incorrect - that needs to be a [time-ordered exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential).

Comment: Even if I have the OE, I am not sure how to generate a state $|\psi(t)\rangle$ from U(t,0)$|\psi(0)\rangle$ due to the integration of p^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there's no fancy math that will save you - you just need to explicitly solve the TDSE numerically for a bunch of different initial conditions.

The algorithm looks more or less like this:

- For each $m=1,\ldots,N_\mathrm{max}$:

  - Formulate the Schrödinger equation for the vector $(\psi_n(t))_{n=1}^{N_\mathrm{max}}$ as a set of coupled ordinary differential equations,
    $$i\hbar \partial_t \psi_n(t) = E_n\psi_n(t)+\sum_{k=1}^{N_\mathrm{max}} Fx_{nk}\psi_k(t) \quad\text{under}\quad \psi_n(t) = \delta_{mn}$$
  - Solve this set of coupled ODEs numerically up to $T=2\pi/\omega$.
  - Store the results at the end of the period as $U_{mn} = \psi_n(T)$. This is known as the monodromy matrix.
- Assemble the results of all the different $m$ into one big matrix $U_{mn}$.
- Diagonalize this matrix. Its eigenvalues are of the form $e^{i \varepsilon_k T/\hbar}$, i.e. the exponentiated quasienergies.
- Repeat for a different coupling.

This is what the authors mean when they say

> then [we] have to deal with a system of $n_\mathrm{max}$ complex coupled ordinary differential equations which can be integrated numerically by standard routines.

I gave this a brief run in Mathematica and it's not that hard (though of course this gets harder and harder as $n_\mathrm{max}$ gets bigger). The results look roughly like this:

[image]

I haven't checked the constants for normalization or the convergence with respect to $n_\mathrm{max}$, so take that as a rough guide only; the code is at

> <sub>Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPjH2.png"]</sub>

Comment: This is awesome.  I think I was getting all confused over trying to integrate the p^2, when that is just the En Yn.  Any chance you could post the Mathematica code (I am dooing this is matlab)

Comment: @yankeefan11 Sorry for the delay, the uploader was playing up.

Comment: What is the significance of the delta function?  In your code, you have initialCondition[m_] := Table[ \[Psi][n][0] == KroneckerDelta[m, n] , {n, 1, Nmax}]  Which is just an Nmax identity matrix?

Comment: That's the initial condition $\psi_n(0)=\delta_{mn}$ above. In essence, you are calculating $U(T,0)|\psi_m\rangle$ for all the different $m$, and then collecting the results together to approximate (the truncation of) $U(T,0)$.